# How to create an alert when new resource is added to resource group using Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler

I have resource group i want to create an alert when a new resource is added to that resource group by using application-Insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Log Analytics workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace) to monitor this behavior(As far as I know, application insights cannot monitor resource group when a new resource is added).

Here are the steps:

1.In azure portal -> your `Log Analytics workspace` -> Logs, write the query like this:

```
AzureActivity 
| where ResourceGroup == "the resource group name" 
| where OperationName == "Create Deployment"
```

2.Then click the `+ New alert rule button`.

[image]

3.In the `Create rule` page, set the proper values as per screenshot below:

[image]

4.Complete other settings.

Please let me know if you still have more issues.

Comment: what is Create Deployment in where OperationName == "Create Deployment"

Comment: When a new resource is added to azure, then in the logs, it will log the information "Create Deployment". So you can consider "create deployment" equals to "add new resource". Hope it helps.